# Possible to force TCP window scaling to a higher value?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

Is it possible to increase the TCP window scaling factor on Linux (CentOS 7.2)? I have a long fat network (100 Mbps) from London to Chicago and I'm getting 16 Mbps throughput in TCP on an sftp from a London machine (Windows Server 2012r2) to my Chicago CentOS machine. I'd like to play with the scaling factor and see if my throughput changes.

My latency is 88 ms roundtrip.

I ask because with UDP I get over 90 Mbps, so I was thinking it would be nice to perhaps double my TCP throughput if I could.

I understand that TCP is connection-oriented, requires an ACK, etc., and that I may actually negatively affect my throughput. What I am doing is second-guessing the wisdom of the makers and trying to assume control myself, rather than allow autotuning to autotune.

Wireshark shows that my sftp from Windows to Linux is indeed using TCP window scaling, so I know it's supported in my path.

Otherwise I'll look into TCP multipath (http://www.multipath-tcp.org/) for my LFN.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using IPv6 or 4?

Comment: IPv4. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: So the very first thing you should do is use v6 which should more fully utilize the bandwidth.  There is a reason carriers abandoned it years ago (aside from exhaustion).

Comment: Do you have numbers to back that claim? Here http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.8351&rep=rep1&type=pdf I quote, "There is no difference between IPv4 and IPv6." Does IPv6 somehow intrinsically multipath TCP or something like this? Otherwise it is subject to the same restrictions of spacetime that IPv4 is. Seems like a big job; I suppose I'll have to configure switches and so on. I want to play with autotune, and your answer is to spend a week employing new technology...? It suppose it must be 1) really easy to do, and 2) a definite win.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/181601/is-ipv6-faster-than-ipv4  "Practical impact? Not really" I observe that mentioned IPv6 speed gains generally come about because of fewer network hops. But this is on a private network, all with known hops and optimized configuration. I don't expect fewer hops whatsoever.

Comment: Do you know for certain that your advertised receive window is less than the bandwidth delay product of your link? Are you able to provide a packet capture?

A quick calculation suggests that as long as your advertised window is greater than around 1MB, you shouldn't be limited by Window Size.

Comment: Linux in Chicago is the receive machine, Windows is pushing the data from London. Under this scenario, Linux' Window size value is 7430 and the scaling factor is 128, for a calculated window size of 941040 (from Wireshark, not sure if that's bits or bytes). The Windows box is advertising a calculated window size of about 252000 IIRC (I didn't screenshot it but I'm 99.9% sure of my number). My BDP is 8,800,000 bits. Regardless, I want to play with the scaling factor if I could, at the very least if only as an experiment.

Comment: I do not believe you can explicitly set the scaling factor used (unless you wanted to write your own TCP stack), however you can increase `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem` which should allow you to increase your minimum, default and maximum window respectively.

In my opinion, it does not sound like Linux receive window size is causing your poor performance.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and had no change in performance, or scaling factors. I actually don't think my performance is bad. Based on http://bradhedlund.com/2008/12/19/how-to-calculate-tcp-throughput-for-long-distance-links/, my performance is on par with what I should be getting... with a 250000 byte window size, I should be getting `250000 / 0.088 == 2.8 MB` of bandwidth. I'm getting 2.2 but that's not including headers and such. So I think I'm close. Again, if I could tweak scaling factor as easily as I could tweak tcp_rmem, I'd like to try.

Comment: @mikes if you treat v4and v6 the same you are correct, no difference, since v6 supports up to a theoretical 4.2GB datagram, I have no doubt that unlike v4, on a private network you can max out the thruput of your networking equipt.  Since the current data thruput record is on IPv6 (9 TB /sec) it would take an Edu to screw thing up so badly that they got the same performance. Now if you are using equipment that can't handle jumbo frames, then absolutely you will see no improvement.

Comment: @JimB - Assuming you're correct, why is it the first thing I would do? I already have a working infrastructure, and tweaking TCP settings takes 5 minutes. Your answer is to drop the protocol entirely and shift to something new. Is it really that simple to do?

Comment: @MikeS Chances are you are already running V6 (I believe centos 7 runs the dual stack ) so it's usually just changing the default to v6 (if it's not already) and if they are on the same network, you will be able to ping6 the link local address (FE80: something).  Once you are using v6 you may see some improvement, from that point on its enabling superjumbo frames on all the switches.  Even if it fragments,source notification will start shrinking the packet until no fragmentation occurs.   A full v6 deployment would naturally take longer but is well worth the effort.

Comment: Are you sure it's tcp and not OpenSSH ? :) Try measuring with how much you get with just plain netcat or iperf or something like that. OpenSSHs internal windowing sucks (or at least it used to). If you do get decent performance out of TCP plain, you could see what tunables exist for OpenSSH and/or give the OpenSSH HPN patchset a try.

Comment: Yes, it's TCP. I had previously run iperf3 tests, bidirectionally, and I show 16 Mbits/sec in both directions on a single stream... same as OpenSSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase tcp window scale factor increasing net.core.rmem_max and net.ipv4.tcp_rmem. When increasing rmem (receiver memory buffer), [indirectly it increases *rcv_wscale](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L243).

For example, increasing receive window buffer to 32MB, I got a window scale factor of 1024:

```
echo 'net.core.rmem_max=33554432' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=4096 33554432 33554432' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

Anyway, reading your previous comments, it seems to me that you have a sender bound throughput, so changing receiver parameters will not improve bps. It's possible to post a capture file?